# Does OAuth2 support cross-user delegation?

Tags: oauth-2.0

Does OAuth2 support the granting of permissions to another user?

I have seen examples of resource owners granting permission to *applications*, but haven't found much about resource owners granting permission to *other users* of those applications.

For example.. Two users: `User` and `Delegate`.

`User` grants permission to `Delegate` to access some resource (via a web interface, perhaps) belonging to `User`. `Delegate` authenticates via OAuth2, and can now see the resource which was protected before `User` granted permission.

In this scenario, `Delegate` would have permission to access everything `Delegate` owns, but also have permission to access some subset of what `User` owns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) there is no native support for cross-user delegation.